# (index):217 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: html, django

receving error message. Ive tried everything i can think of and being a novice im at a loss. please help

```
    DisplayCart(cart);
    function DisplayCart(cart){
        var cartString = "";
        cartString += "<h5>This is your cart</h5>";
        var cartIndex = 1;

        for(var x in cart){
            cartString += cartIndex;
            cartString += document.getElementById("nm"+x).innerHTML +  "QTY:" + cart[x];
            cartIndex += 1;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: `getElementById("nm"+x)` didn't find any element with that ID, so it returned null.

Comment: i have no idea how to fix this. the code below is the only other place"nm" is no my code
```
        <div class="row">
            {% for product in product_objects %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="{{ product.image }}" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="nm{{ product.id }}" class="card-title">
                            {{ product.title }}
                        </div>
                   ${{ product.price }}
```